# How to replace dash with a space from an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, replace, gsub

How can I replace dashes with a spaces & underscores with a commas at the same time?

I was able to replace underscores with commas, but when I tried to reiterate through the array again it gave some funky results.

Controller

```
  def activity_by_all_city
      @cities = ['Abilene_Texas','Akron_Ohio','Albuquerque_New-Mexico','Baton-Rouge_Louisiana']
  end
```

View

```
<% @cities.each do |city|%>
    <%= link_to city.gsub!(/_/, ', '), 'activities-'+city.parameterize %><br>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
<%= link_to city.replace(city.gsub(/-/, ' ').gsub(/_/, ', ')), 'activities-'+city.parameterize %><br>
```

Gives:

```
<a href="activities-albuquerque-new-mexico">Albuquerque, New Mexico</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use [String#tr](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-tr-21) to replace a set of characters with another:

```
@cities.collect {|city| city.tr('-_', ' ,') }
=> ["Abilene,Texas", "Akron,Ohio", "Albuquerque,New Mexico", "Baton Rouge,Louisiana"]
```

The above will create a new list, keeping the original `@cities` strings intact.
If you use the destructive version (String#tr!), the strings will be modified in place, making `@cities` hold the translated city names:

```
@cities.each {|city| city.tr!('-_', ' ,') }
=> ["Abilene,Texas", "Akron,Ohio", "Albuquerque,New Mexico", "Baton Rouge,Louisiana"]
@cities
=> ["Abilene,Texas", "Akron,Ohio", "Albuquerque,New Mexico", "Baton Rouge,Louisiana"]
```

(This principle applies to all "destructive" methods, also `gsub!`, they alter the object they are applied to.)

Comment: The author tried to replace spaces with ', ' (comma + space). I guess this isn't suitable for the `tr` method.

Comment: True. I did not interpret the question this way, but if this is what was intended you are of course correct.